# How to implement Mongoose schema validations at database level?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

We are building a set of micro-services, using a single database. One service, built with express, is provided the access for database management, i.e. schema validations, collection creation etc. 
That service is using `mongoose` to do all this. However, we now see that mongoose implements the validations on the application layer. Meaning that no validations are enforced when other services insert documents into collections or make updates.
We cannot export these mongoose models to be used by other services due to them being in different platforms and frameworks. The solution we see right now is to re-factor the main express service to use the traditional MongoClient instead of mongoose and implement the MongoDB JSON validations at the database level.
Before this, we would like to consider if there is a way to enforce the mongoose schemas at a Database level rather than the application level. If so, how can that be done.
Thanks!